# Data Field Validation in the Data Model dosen't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I am simply trying to validate a phone number that the user will enter using Data field validation in my model I have searched how to do it and here's what I have as of now ( I tried to follow the information i saw on msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488527.aspx):

This is my Metadata file :

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.DynamicData;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace InscriptionCentreFormation.Models
{

  [MetadataType(typeof(INSC_InscriptionMetadata))]
  public partial class INSC_Inscription
  {


  }
  public class INSC_InscriptionMetadata
  {
    [Display(Name = "Mobile Phone")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid format")] //Vérifie le format du tel
    public string TelephoneMobile { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Home Phone")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid format")] //Vérifie le format du tel
    public string TelephoneMaison { get; set; }
  }

}
```

And this is the Generated Model class :

```
namespace InscriptionCentreFormation.Models
{
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 public partial class INSC_Inscription
 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int idOccurenceFormation { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneMobile { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneMaison { get; set; }  
  }

}
```

And finally here is a simplified version of the registration page :

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using InscriptionCentreFormation.Controllers
@using InscriptionCentreFormation.Models
@model INSC_Inscription
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "InscriptionFormation";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("InscriptionFormation", "DetailProduit"))
{
    <div style="width:800px;">
        <span style="float:left"><b>Mobile phone :</b></span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TelephoneMobile, new { Style = "float:right;width:400px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TelephoneMobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="float:left"><b>Home phone :</b></span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TelephoneMaison, new { Style = "float:right;width:400px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TelephoneMaison, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="S'inscrire" style="width:200px; text-align:center;"/>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

But the problem is that when I try to register no validation happens on either of the phone number and just can't seem to grasp why, I saw some solutions like adding the scripts at the bottom of the registration page but it still won't work.

Any hints towards a solution would really help

Comment: Did you register your ModelBinders in Application start method?

Comment: Add this line in `ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.DataAnnotationsModelBinder();` in Application_start() in global.asax or in your Startup.cs.

Comment: @vendettamit it says Mvc dosen't exist it Microsoft.web

Comment: Add the using statement `using System.Web.Mvc;`

Comment: @vendettamit its already there

Comment: I got it.. use `System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.DataAnnotationsModelBinder‌​()` the `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` is the nuget package one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143990/discussion-between-louis-roch-tessier-and-vendettamit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties in meta data class doesn't have to be of same type as in Actual model class. Try changing your meta data class properties to:

```
  public class INSC_InscriptionMetadata
  {
    [Display(Name = "Mobile Phone")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid format")] //Vérifie le format du tel
    public object TelephoneMobile { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Home Phone")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid format")] //Vérifie le format du tel
    public object TelephoneMaison { get; set; }
  }
```

**Update**

Add JQuery validation scripts in your page if not already there:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
```

Check in your controller if ModelState is valid:

```
public ActionResult InscriptionFormation(INSC_Inscription insc)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();
..
..
}
```

I've replicated your code and these are the things I found were missing to make validation work.

Also validate on the same view instead of navigating it to other view for validating Model. Only navigate if the model is valid and should be processed by another page. This would help you keep things simple.